# How do I setup a relationship between one type of user & a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a `Vendor` and a `User`. A user can have one of many roles: `superadmin`, `admin`, `vendor`, `user`.

My `Vendor` model is essentially a "store".

I want the users with the role `vendor` to own an instance of the model `Vendor`. But not all users will own an instance of the model `Vendor`.

In my `Vendor` model, I have this:

```
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User",
    :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

But I am not sure what to do with the `User` model, because not every `User` will have one or have many vendors.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking into the [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem by Ryan Bates, particularly [this functionality](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan#2-check-abilities--authorization). This should help you with both establishing your roles and controlling privileges on the Vendor objects.

As far as the association is concerned, you should still use `has_many vendors` from the sound of your use case and then control access from the controller.

Comment: I am using CanCan actually. But it is the association I am a bit unsure about. If I do `has_many :vendors`, will there be any issues when there are users that don't have a `vendor` assigned to it?

Comment: marcamillion, that is great, CanCan is a great gem. There should not be any problem with using the `has_many` relationship, even though the relationship is there a user does not have to have a `vendor` it only means that a user has the capacity to have a `vendor`. That is why you would have to control the access using the roles you have established in CanCan. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
User

has_one :store

Store

belongs_to :user
```

And only let Users that are vendors make a store. in Store Controller

```
before_filter :authenticate_vendor!

def authenticate_vendor!
  # redirect unless user is vendor
end
```

Comment: The issue with this is that not every `User` will have one store. In fact, some users won't have any stores. Some users will shop in many stores.

Comment: not every `User` needs a store. They *can* have one. For stroes shopped at I'd have a method that grabs stores by the items purchased at the store, and have each item belong to a store

Comment: Yeh...I have the item & the store relation going fine. I think a hybrid between yours & @jason-truluck's suggestion about CanCan may be what I need. The `has_one :vendor` is what I may go with.

Comment: good luck! Last thought- if you say `x is essentially a "y"` you should probly just call it a y

Comment: Is there an easy way to change the name of a resource? (i.e. controller, model, tables, migrations, schema, routes, everything)? like a `rake task` or a rails command or something? The model is called `Vendor` now, but I recognize that is a role and wouldn't mind changing it to `Store` - just don't want to have to go through every single thing and change it. The only way I know is to destroy the resource and re-create. Not in a hurry to do that.

Comment: To rename a resource, you have to add one migration that renames the table, and rename model, controller and route manually. It is actually not that hard at all.